# What function does Linux use to get an absolute path?

Tags: linux, kernel, symlink, pathname

If the kernel or a kernel module has a path that has symbolic link components, is relative, or is both, what function does it use to turn `../bob` into `/home/bob` or `/etc/mtab` into `/proc/self/mount`? How can I also get the absolute path of a file as it is on the filesytem it belongs to (i.e., turning `/proc/kcore` into `/kcore`)? I am assuming that the parameter cannot be a string but must be a struct like `pathname`.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're looking for [getname](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/fs/namei.c?v=4.7#L205).
You can trace it back from the [open](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/fs/open.c?v=4.7#L1029) syscall.

Comment: Will it turn `../bob` into `/home/bob` and `/etc/mtab` into `/proc/self/mounts`?

Comment: `insmod` says it is an unknown symbol.